# Annotate a Line that is Split Into Multiple Segments With an Annotation for Each Segment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, annotation

How do I annotate a line that is Split into multiple segments with an annotation for each segment? It is giving the line a single annotation when it needs an annotation on each split segment. As you can see in the picture the blue line is pointing to the each label, but when I convert it to annotation it only labels the line once instead of an annotation for each segment. The line is segmented where it intersects the polygons. Using ArcMap 10.3.1. [image]

Comment: It would be helpful to know what software you are using.

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose to place one label per feature part by changing the Duplicate Labels option in the Placement Properties menu of the Label Manager:
[image: Add Duplicate Labels per feature part]

for more info:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/prioritizing-and-positioning-labels-working-with-d.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response, this does indeed work. I had to turn off my maplex engine in order to correct the issue.